# How do I "Order by" more than on column?

Tags: enums, sql-order-by

This is my query:

```
SELECT count(oi.id) imgCnt, o.*, 
IF(pricet=2,c.currency_value*o.attributes_36*o.price,
c.currency_value*o.price) AS pprice, od.title, oi.image, 
MIN(oi.id), ( c.currency_value * o.price ) AS fprice, 
ag.agent_name, DATE_FORMAT( o.date_added, '%d-%m-%Y') as dadded 
FROM i_offers_12 o 
LEFT JOIN i_agents ag ON o.agents_id = ag.id 
LEFT JOIN i_currencies c ON o.currencies_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN i_offers_details od ON ( o.id = od.offers_id AND od.languages_id = 1 ) 
LEFT JOIN i_offers_images oi ON ( oi.offers_id = o.id AND oi.o_id = '12' ) 
WHERE ( o.offer_status='active' OR o.offer_status='sold') 
AND actions_id = '1' 
AND c.id = o.currencies_id 
AND o.counties_id = '2' 
AND o.cities_id = '3' 
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY dadded
DESC
```

I want to sort after dadded(which is of type date) and `offer_status`(which is of type enum). 
I want to display first, all of the elements which have `offer_status` = 'active' and sort by `dadded` and after that all of the elements which have `offer_status` = 'sold' and sort also by dadded. How can I do that? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields you want to sort on MUST be part of the select statement:

```
  SELECT count(oi.id) imgCnt, o.*, 
    IF(pricet=2,c.currency_value*o.attributes_36*o.price,
    c.currency_value*o.price) AS pprice, od.title, oi.image, 
    MIN(oi.id), ( c.currency_value * o.price ) AS fprice, 
    ag.agent_name, DATE_FORMAT( o.date_added, '%d-%m-%Y') as dadded ,
    offer_status
    FROM i_offers_12 o 
    LEFT JOIN i_agents ag ON o.agents_id = ag.id 
    LEFT JOIN i_currencies c ON o.currencies_id = c.id 
    LEFT JOIN i_offers_details od ON ( o.id = od.offers_id AND od.languages_id = 1 ) 
    LEFT JOIN i_offers_images oi ON ( oi.offers_id = o.id AND oi.o_id = '12' ) 
    WHERE ( o.offer_status='active' OR o.offer_status='sold') 
    AND actions_id = '1' 
    AND c.id = o.currencies_id 
    AND o.counties_id = '2' 
    AND o.cities_id = '3' 
    AND o.offer_status='active' 
    GROUP BY o.id
    ORDER BY offer_status, dadded
    DESC
```

Note that you normally should group by ALL non summarized fields (o.*, 
    IF(pricet=2,c.currency_value*o.attributes_36*o.price,
    c.currency_value*o.price) AS pprice, od.title, oi.image, ( c.currency_value * o.price ) AS fprice, 
    ag.agent_name, DATE_FORMAT( o.date_added, '%d-%m-%Y') as dadded ,
    offer_status)

MySQL is not enforcing it, but other DB like Oracle does.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can write the SQL with

```
ORDER BY offer_status, dadded
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comma, like

```
ORDER BY supplier_city DESC, supplier_state ASC;
```